# Prove that if $n\ge4$ then $n,n+2,n+4$ cannot all be primes.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My question is well written in title. I thought that something like divisibility by $3$ will work but it is not. Please help.

Comment: Are you sure divisibility by 3 doesn't work?

Comment: $n$ is one of $0,1,2 \pmod 3$.  Just try each case.

Comment: Possibly related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64414/show-that-every-prime-p3-is-either-of-the-form-6n1-or-of-the-form-6n5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Notice that when $n\ge4$, $$3|n(n+2)(n+4)$$ If you want to prove it, consider making cases when $n$ is even and when $n$ is odd.

Answer (score 5):

Let $m=n+2$; then the product of the three numbers is $$\begin{array}{rcl}(m-2)m(m+2)&=&m^3-4m \\ &\equiv& m^3-m\pmod3 \\ &\equiv& 0\pmod3\end{array}$$
since $m^3\equiv m\pmod3$. So $3$ divides the product of the numbers and so it divides one of them. As $n>3$, that number cannot be $3$ itself; hence it is not prime.

Comment: $m^3-m=m(m-1)(m+1)$

Comment: @Nil What's your point?

Comment: Product of three consecutive integers is divisible by $3!.$  I just want to mention it.

Answer (score 1):

if $$n\equiv 1\mod 3$$ then we have $$n+2\equiv 0 \mod 3$$
if $$n\equiv 2 \mod 3$$ then we have $$n+4\equiv 0 \mod 3$$
note that if we have $$n=3$$ then we get the prime numbers $$3,5,7$$