# Proof-verification: Any prime $p>3$ can be expressed in the form $(6n+1)$ or $(6n+5)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, solution-verification

I have already seen answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/64414/show-that-every-prime-p3-is-either-of-the-form-6n1-or-of-the-form-6n5), but I would like to get my own proof verified.

> **Proposition:** Any prime $p>3$ can be expressed in the form $(6n+1)$ or $(6n+5)$.

> **Definition:** A prime $p$ is a natural number greater than $1$ which is divisible only by $1$ and itself. Thus, no prime $p>3$ is divisible by $3$.

> **Proof:** $$p=3n'+r\;\mathrm{where}\;0<r<3$$
> $r\neq 0,3$ because stating otherwise would imply divisibility by 3. The above statement is equivalent to saying: $$(p=3n'+1)\,\mathrm{or}\,(p=3n'+2)$$ Further, $(3n'+2)\equiv5\mod3\iff(3n'+5)\equiv2\mod3$. Thus, $$p=(3n'+1)\;\mathrm{or}\;p=(3n'+5)$$Substituting $n'=2n$, we get: $$p=(6n+1)\;\mathrm{or}\;p=(6n+5)$$ Which completes the proof.

I'm sceptical of the step where I used congruence to switch $2$ and $5$. **I would like to know the flaws in my proof, and measures that I can take to rectify them.**

Comment: This doesn’t quite show why they can’t be $6n+2$ or $6n+4$, which are $2$ and $1$ modulo $3$, respectively. Fortunately, you can easily show they cannot be the case (why?).

Comment: @paulinho As suggested by Michael in his answer below, even parity would imply divisibility by 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your proof, you need to consider the case where $n'$ is odd: when $n' = 2k+1$ for a positive integer $k$. When $n'$ is odd, what happens to the parity of $p$ in both cases?

Comment: Noted, thanks! I should have avoided an arbitrary substitution like that.

Comment: Splitting the problem into cases is an effective strategy, so if you justify your reasoning this way, your proof is fine. However, in hindsight, Michael Rozenberg's proof is much shorter.

Answer (score 4):

Let $n$ be a non-negative integer number.

We see that $6n$ is divisible by $6$, $6n+2=2(3n+1)$ is divisible by $2$,

$6n+3=3(2n+1)$ is divisible by $3$ and $6n+4=2(3n+2)$ is divisible by $2$.

Id est, may be $p=6n+1$ or $p=6n+5$ only.